# ASP.NET Button Click Event Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, event-handling

I have a `Main.Master` page with a button.
When in Design view I double click that button it creates a click event in `Main.Master` page like below;

```
<script runat="server">

    protected void btnKayit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
</script>
```

I want it to create at `Main.Master.cs` page, when I do this maually it gives me this error;

```
CS1061: 'ASP.main_master' does not contain a definition for 'btnKayit_Click' and no extension method 'btnKayit_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.main_master' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

How can I solve this problem?

EDIT: aspx code;

```
<asp:Button CssClass="arama" ID="btnKayit" runat="server" Text="Kayıt Ol" Height="30px"
                                    Width="75px" Style="margin: 0px; float: left; width: 75px; padding: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;
                                    color: #d55355; font-size: 12px" onclick="btnKayit_Click" />
```

Comment: Sounds like a namespace issue. Is this an asp.net website rather than ASP.net web forms?

Comment: show ur aspx page code. Also check button control properly initialized on aspx.designer.cs page.

Comment: @DaveHogan this is Web Application project

Comment: @watraplion I checked designer.cs it initialized properly

Comment: check the page directive and inheritance in aspx.cs page.

Comment: Possible causes: 1) You have not compiled 2) Misspelling the name of the handler method (..._click) 3) Mismatch namespace specified in the @Page directive and codebehind 4) etc

Answer (score 0):

Verify namespace in both .master and .master.cs file.

Check directive of master file...

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Main.Master.css"
Inherits="Main" EnableTheming="true" %>
```

Here, check name of CodeFile attribute, it should be same as class name of Master.cs file

```
public partial class Main : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
```

Comment: It's same but there is CodeBehind decleration instead of CodeFile. Do u think this is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As per your error message, I think your master page is inheriting `ASP.main_master` class. You need to add `btnKayit_Click()` in the `ASP.main_master` class. Basically, your code should look like following.

HTML:

```
//Please note the inherits attribute
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="main_master" ... %>


<asp:Button CssClass="arama" ID="btnKayit" runat="server" ... 
            onclick="btnKayit_Click" />
```

Code behind:

```
//Please note the class name here it should be same as inheriting class name
public partial class main_master : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    //....

    protected void btnKayit_Click(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```